# Displaying an ad on a new thread

Tags: java, android, startapp

I have a game with different screens. To show an ad on a specific screen I use the method below which use thread. Everything works fine but the ads keeps loading and new ads popup. I want that the ad loads only once.
How can I create a thread so the ad methods are called only once.

```
public void displayAd(){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            startAppAd.showAd(); // show the ad
            startAppAd.loadAd(); // load the next ad
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: We don't have enough information to answer this question. Have you tried logging inside the `displayAd()` method to see if that method is being called numerous times?

Comment: You are right I have called the displayAd() on the update method.